# What is `export type` in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I notice the following syntax in Typescript.

```
export type feline = typeof cat;
```

As far as I know, `type` is not a [built-in basic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html), nor it is an interface or class. Actually it looks more like a syntax for aliasing, which however I can't find reference to verify my guess.

So what does the above statement mean?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

This is a [*type alias*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) - it's used to give another name to a type.

(Compare [type vs interface here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces))

In your example, `feline` will be the type of whatever `cat` is.

Here's a more full fledged example:

```
interface Animal {
    legs: number;
}

const cat: Animal = { legs: 4 };

export type feline = typeof cat;
```

`feline` will be the type `Animal`, and you can use it as a type wherever you like.

```
const someFunc = (cat: feline) => {
    doSomething(cat.legs);
};
```

`export` simply exports it from the file. It's the same as doing this:

```
type feline = typeof cat;

export {
    feline
};
```

Comment: The simplest example is string literal types:
`type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";`

Comment: I can't understand in depth. What's the difference between an interface and a type then? What is type majorly used for?

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye https://pawelgrzybek.com/typescript-interface-vs-type/

Comment: I went through the link also, but still not completely clear.

Comment: @KapilRaghuwanshi Microsoft thought someone could have been confused and wrote a [paragraph about their difference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases). As they say, a rule of thumb might be "Prefer interface over type whenever you can".

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/types-vs-interfaces-in-typescript/ try this one too