# Why is `export type` necessary with `--isolatedModules`?

Tags: typescript, type-only-import-export

I don't understand what is happening or why it's made to do this under the hood:

- If `Something` is a type, why does `export { SomeThing } from "elsewhere"` produce an error when `--isolatedModules` is enabled?

  Conversely why is `export { SomeThing } from "elsewhere"` not an error if `Something` is a value, or if `--isolatedModules` is not enabled?
- Why does specifying `export type { SomeThing } from "elsewhere"` fix that error?

---

**(Background information)**

There is [a new TypeScript feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html):

> **Type-Only Imports and Export**
>
> This feature is something most users may never have to think about;
> however, if you’ve hit issues under `--isolatedModules`, TypeScript’s
> `transpileModule` API, or Babel, this feature might be relevant.
>
> TypeScript 3.8 adds a new syntax for type-only imports and exports.
>
> ```js
> import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";
>
> export type { SomeThing };
> ```
>
> `import type` only imports declarations to be used for type
> annotations and declarations. It *always* gets fully erased, so
> there’s no remnant of it at runtime. Similarly, `export type` only
> provides an export that can be used for type contexts, and is also
> erased from TypeScript’s output.

I know how to use it and when it's necessary but I don't know why, i.e. apparently when `--isolatedModules` is enabled then code like the following ...

```js
import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";

export { SomeThing };
```

... produces a compiler error i.e. ...

```
Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided requires using 'export type'.ts(1205)
```

... and the fix is to use `export type { SomeThing }` instead of `export { SomeThing }`.

Incidentally though, apparently `import { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js"` is OK, doesn't produce an error message, `import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js"` is not required.

---

By the way this is not the same topic as [What is `export type` in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44079820/49942) which is about defining a `type` and prefixing it with `export`, in 2017 before this new feature was implemented.

Comment: Because the transpiler cannot make sure that the imported name is a type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [this Babel Github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6065), where it is explained:

> In order to determine whether something is a type, we need information
> about other modules.
>
> ```js
> import { T } from "./other-module";
> export { T }; // Is this a type export?
> ```

There's also a great elaborated explanation on [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/e9span/isolatedmodules_prevents_exporting_a_type_from_a/):

> type space is TypeScript's domain: all of the types that make up your
> app. They only exist at compile time. Once the compiler is done, the
> resulting JavaScript has no types left in it. Value space is basically
> the opposite: it's the stuff that sticks around and survives into the
> JS.
>
> ```js
> type Foo = { bar: string };
> const a: Foo = { bar: 'hello' };
> ```
>
> Here, `Foo` is in the type space,
> everything else is in the value space.
>
> The problem with `isolatedModules`, is they can't know which space they
> are working with, since each file is compiled individually. So if you
> do:
>
> ```js
> export { Foo } from './bar';
> ```
>
> in a file, TypeScript can't know if `Foo`
> is in the type space (if it is, it just gets thrown away as it won't
> be in the resulting JavaScript), or if it is in the value space (ie
> it's JS, so it needs to be included in the resulting output).