# Optional parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a type that needs to feed in optional parameters.

```
export type Dep = {
    createRole: boolean;
    namespace: string;
};
```

And I am using this variable like this

```
if (args.createRole) {
            this.role = createRoleAndServiceAccount(
                args.namespace,
            )
        }
```

This is the function

```
function createRoleAndServiceAccount(
    namespace: string,
) { ...
```

I want to call this `Dep` with or without the parameters. And any code that uses this, should be able to work still with maybe some default values for these. How do I do that?

I tried something like this

```
export type Dep = {
    createRole?: boolean;
    namespace?: string;
};
```

But when I try to use these values, it says,

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This is how I am trying to create the Dep

```
new Dep ("Druid dependencies", {
        createRole: true,
        namespace: "druid"
    }, {});
```

I also added default values by something like

```
export type Dep = {
    createRole?: boolean;
    namespace?: string;
};
```

But it still does not work

Comment: _How_ do you try to use those values? You mention default values, but don't show how you've tried to provide them.

Comment: Use an inteface not a type

https://www.becomebetterprogrammer.com/typescript-question-mark/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079820/what-is-export-type-in-typescript

Comment: The error is about a function parameter, but you've only shown us type declarations. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I added them in the question as well

Comment: `new Dep` isn't going to work at all because that's a _type_, not a _class_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to use a variable that is `string | undefined` where a string is needed, say for a function `f(s: string)`, you need to either A) conditionally call the function with that variable only if you're sure it's not undefined, or B) assert that you are sure it's not undefined

A) compiler knows you've checked that your string is not undefined:

```
if(myDep.namespace){
   f(myDep.namespace)
}
```

B) Use the bang like this to assert that the value is definitely not undefined (use with caution -- not generally recommended):

```
f(myDep.namespace!)
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with option A.